# operations on relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I need help to verify my solutions.

I have two relations.

$(x,y)Pz :\iff x + y = z$  and $(x,y)Mz: \iff x - y = z$

the quest is what is
the symbols are defined like this.
$xP;Qz := \exists y:xpPy \land yQz$ 
$\text{converse}(xRy) := \{(y,x)|(x,y \in R)\} $

a) $(1,2).P;\text{converse}(M)$
b) $P;\text{converse}(P).(u,v)$
c) $(x,y)(P \cap M).\text{converse}(P\cup M)$

so my solution is:
a) $(1,2)P(3) \text{converse} (M)(x,y||x > y \land x-y=3)$
b) $(u,v)P;\text{converse}(P)(u,v)$
c) I really have problems with c.what I have is 
   $(x,y)(P∩M)( \emptyset ) .\text{converse}(P∪M) $ 
I don't know what the last step for c is and I hope someone can tell me if a and b is right.

Comment: I've edited the first paragraph so it will be readable. Please see my edits and apply them to the second and third paragraphs.

Comment: For $xP;Qz$ see [Composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations).

Comment: You have defined above what is the [Converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) of a relation.